# Dialogbox on List onListItemClick() method .. It give BadTokenException

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog

I want to setup the Dialog on list.When the user select the list item, it should show alert box with "Yes" /"No".I have tried like this. but it give **BadTokenException**

```
     @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String, String> itemAtPosition = (HashMap<String, String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = itemAtPosition;
        keyword = hashMap.get("routeCode");
        positions = position;
        if(itinerarySelection.equals("1") || itinerarySelection.equals(" ") ||itinerarySelection == null){
            AlertDialog.Builder routeDefaultQue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            routeDefaultQue.setMessage("Do you want to set this route as defalut route?");
            routeDefaultQue.setCancelable(false);
            routeDefaultQue.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//                      String[] nameFilds = {"BusinessUnit","ExecutiveCode","VisitNumber","TerritoryCode","RouteCode","VisitDate","StartTime","Status","UploadedOn","UploadedBy"};
//                      String[] valuesFilds = {strBusinessUnit,strExecutive,"",strTerritoryCode,keyword,DateFormat.getInstance().format(date),DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date),"1",DateFormat.getInstance().format(date),strExecutive};
//                      insertRecords("", nameFilds, valuesFilds);
//                      getListView().getChildAt(positions).setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                }
            });
            routeDefaultQue.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            routeDefaultQue.setTitle("Default Route setup...");
            routeDefaultQue.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            routeDefaultQue.show();
         }
```

This is i am doing this list on activityGroup.

This is error

```
    08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4056e178 is not valid; is your activity running?
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at com.xont.controller.sales.SalesRouteActivity.onListItemClick(SalesRouteActivity.java:145)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-25 10:29:46.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(597):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the content of a Tab is an Activity then you need to pass the context of the TabActivity to things like alert dialogs rather than the content activity's context.

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder routeDefaultQue = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder routeDefaultQue = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourRunningActivity.this);
```

try this

Comment: No.This is not working.If we call `getParent()` then its working.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you are using the wrong `context` here, try to use the right context that you are passing to the AlertDialog.Builder and 
your problem will be done.

You have used this

```
AlertDialog.Builder routeDefaultQue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

inside the `onListItemClick` and you are passing `this` to create the AlertDialog.Builder which is wrong, you have to pass a context of Activity or Application there.

Comment: Yes.This correct. `AlertDialog.Builder routeDefaultQue = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());`

Answer (score 1):

Try below, Code

```
AlertDialog.Builder routeDefaultQue = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```